# I download the anaconda successfully while having error when I try to import matplotlib in spyder?

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

[image: Here] is my code that I have copied from others in order to test my Python and the third party libraries. Unfortunately, it is not working. The code analysis shows "pyplot imported but unused". Can anyone explain and give me some advice to fix this problem?

Comment: In the code snippet that you showed, there is no use of matplotlib. It may just be a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Peaceful  thanks for your offer.One of my friends told me the same idea as yours.Now I am able to run my code normally with python.BTW, I find the Jupyter IDE is more powerful and easy to do a python programming.